# Calculate Knuth's up arrow notation

Tags: code-golf, math

<sup>Inspired by [Expand exponentation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/110596/expand-exponentiation).</sup>

[Knuth's up arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is used for big numbers such as Graham's number.

If we look deeper, we can see how it makes big numbers.

One arrow means exponentiation. e.g. 2↑3 equals 2^3 = 8.

Two or more arrows means repeating the instructions of n-1 arrows. e.g. 2↑↑3 equals 2↑2↑2 equals 2^(2^2)=16.

You will be given three integers, n, a, and m. n is the first number, a is the amount of arrows, and m is the second number.

Your code should output the final answer, which is the calculation of `n ↑a m`<sup>(↑x means there are x up-arrows, where x is an integer)</sup>

## Examples

```
2 1 2 -> 4
2 1 3 -> 8
2 2 3 -> 16
2 3 3 -> 65536
```

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83873/8478)

Comment: I'd suggest to add `3 2 2` and `3 2 3` as additional test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
{×⍺⍺:(⍺⍺-1)∇∇/⍵/⍺⋄⍺×⍵}
```

This is an operator that takes `a` as its operand (`⍺⍺`), and `n` and `m` as its left and right arguments (`⍺` and `⍵`).

Explanation:

- `×⍺⍺`: if `⍺⍺` is positive:

  - `⍵/⍺`: replicate `⍺` `⍵` times
  - `(⍺⍺-1)∇∇/`: fold the `⍺⍺-1`-arrow function over the list.
- `⋄`: otherwise (i.e. if `⍺⍺` is zero):

  - `⍺×⍵`: multiply the arguments

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, 121 bytes

```
int c(int n,int a,int m){return(int)(a<2?Math.pow(n,m):d(n,a));}double d(int n,int a){return Math.pow(n,a<2?n:d(n,a-1));}
```

**Explanation:**

```
int c(int n, int a, int m){         // Main method with the three integer-parameters as specified by OP's challenge
  return (int)                      // Math.pow returns a double, so we cast it to an integer
          (a < 2 ?                  // if (a == 1):
                   Math.pow(n, m)   //  Use n^m
                 :                  // else (a > 1):
                   d(n, a));        //  Use method d(n, a)
}

double d(int n, int a){             // Method d with two integer-parameters
  return Math.pow(n, a < 2          // n ^ X where
                      ? n           //  X = n    if (a == 1)
                      : d(n, a-1)); //  X = recursive call d(n, a-1)    if (a > 1)
}

// In pseudo-code:
c(n, a, m){
  if a == 1: return n^m
  if a > 1:  return d(n, a);
}
d(n, a){
  if a == 1: return n^n
  if a > 1:  return d(n, a-1);
}
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/7WFfZM)

```
class M{
  static int c(int n,int a,int m){return(int)(a<2?Math.pow(n,m):d(n,a));}
  static double d(int n,int a){return Math.pow(n,a<2?n:d(n,a-1));}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(2, 1, 2));
    System.out.println(c(2, 1, 3));
    System.out.println(c(2, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(c(2, 3, 3));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
4
8
16
65536
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in the challenge definition, I don't think that `m` should be ignored when `a > 1`.

Comment: @Arnauld The way I read the challenge it is, unless I'm missing something.. :S I do get the correct output. How do you interpret OP's question, and could you come up with a test case where that interpretation would differ in terms of output compared to my pseudo-code explanation?

Comment: I think we should have `3 2 2 -> 3^3 = 27` and `3 2 3 -> 3^(3^3) = 7625597484987`. (You can find these examples -- and more of them -- on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth's_up-arrow_notation))

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES7, <strike>53</strike> 44 bytes

```
f=(a,b,c)=>b<2||c<1?a**c:f(a,b-1,f(a,b,c-1))
```

```js
f=(a,b,c)=>b<2||c<1?a**c:f(a,b-1,f(a,b,c-1))

console.log(f(2,1,2));
console.log(f(2,1,3));
console.log(f(2,2,3));
console.log(f(2,3,3));
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, <s>48</s> 40 bytes

```
If[#3>1<#,#0[#0[#-1,##2],#2,#3-1],#2^#]&
```

Order of arguments is `m, n, a` (using the notation from the challenge).

Answer (score 0):

## julia, <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```julia
f(a,n,b)=b>1< n?f(a,n-1,f(a,n,b-1)):a^b
```

Thanks to @Martin 3 bytes saved.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@5@mkaiTp5OkaZtkZ2iTZw/m6hrqQIV1DTU1rRLjkv4XFGXmleTkaaRpGOkY6xhrav4HAA)

**a,b** : operands
**n**: number of arrows

Previous answer:

```julia
f(a,n,b)=n<2||b<1?a^b:f(a,n-1,f(a,n,b-1))
```

Modified formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#@5@mkaiTp5OkaZtnY1RTk2RjaJ8Yl2QFFtU11IHK6hpqav4vKMrMK8nJ00jTMNIx1jEGigAA)

Comment: You can save some bytes on the `||` by a) noting that `b<2` also works, b) applying deMorgan to rewrite that as `n>1&&b>1` (swapping the two branches of the ternary operator) and c) using inequality chaining on the `1`: `f(a,n,b)=b>1<n?f(a,n-1,f(a,n,b-1)):a^b`